# XML loading Issue with jmx generated by Blazemeter Mobile Recorder

Tags: jmeter, performance, blazemeter

I am trying to record a Mobile Native App with Blazemeter Mobile Recorder. After recording I have generated the **smart jmx** file. But the issue is, this jmx file is not getting opened up with JMeter **though i can load simple jmx file generated by blazemeter for same requests**. i am using

```
1. jmeter 3.1 , had also tried with jmeter 2.13
2. Java 1.8
```

I have also **tried adding standard jar files and plugins in ext folder of jmeter, but all in vain**.

Below are the logs from jmeter

```
2016/12/20 11:06:06 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils: JMeter-Plugins.org v.1.4.0 
2016/12/20 11:06:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.assertions.BSFAssertion 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.extractor.BSFPostProcessor 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.BSFPreProcessor 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2016/12/20 11:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 
2016/12/20 11:06:08 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool' 
2016/12/20 11:06:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file D:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2016/12/20 11:06:08 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler 
2016/12/20 11:06:08 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement 
2016/12/20 11:06:08 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler 
2016/12/20 11:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.timers.BSFTimer 
2016/12/20 11:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.BSFListener 
2016/12/20 11:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.MonitorHealthVisualizer 
2016/12/20 11:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2016/12/20 11:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2016/12/20 11:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2016/12/20 11:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='D:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin' 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\keshav.joshi\Desktop\Smart_12_20,_2016,_5_36_am.jmx 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\keshav.joshi\Desktop' 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 3.1 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2016/12/20 11:06:21 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: C:\Users\keshav.joshi\Desktop\Smart_12_20,_2016,_5_36_am.jmx 
2016/12/20 11:06:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2016/12/20 11:06:22 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\keshav.joshi\Desktop\Smart_12_20,_2016,_5_36_am.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[6]/hashTree[6]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 534
version             : 3.1 r1770033
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:537)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:505)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[6]/hashTree[6]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 534
version             : 3.1 r1770033
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.createConversionException(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:103)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:97)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:522)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[6]/hashTree[6]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 534
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:72)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart JMX is a converting mechanism which converts the BlazeMeter proxy recording into a JMX while adding further logics, e.g necessary parameterizations as well as token or sessionID extractions etc. for the latter, one of the JMeter elements used is actually a JSON path extractor which is a JMeter plugin. in order to be able to open this JMX in your JMeter installation you will have to have this plugin installed. In order to do so, go to jmeter-plugins.org and download the plugin manager. After you've succesfully installed it, in JMeter go to option-> plugin manager and add the plugins you wish. For this example you provided you will need 'at least' the 'JSON plugins'.

You will find more information regarding JMeter's plugin manager [in this blog post.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
Regardless, feel free to approach BlazeMeter support at support@blazemeter.com for any BlazeMeter related issue.

Comment: With a fresh Jmeter install, our older jmx files didn't work.  Downloading the plugin manager helped b/c it knew which plugin we were missing.